# media query for orientation change in android

Tags: android, html, webview, orientation, media-queries

i have a website, that is created to be loaded by the webview on android devices
so basically what i am expecting is that the website i am going to load will fit on the screen, i.e. there should not be anything overflowing the page and introduce scrolling

when you load the site in webview in portrait mode, it loads fine, i mean everything is in place, no overflow whatever, image are in its correct size, if i change it to landscape while viewing the webview, everything is still cool, it still scales and displays the same view as it were in portrait mode, u just get that extra space around it.

however, if i load the webview in landscape mode first, it seems the content of my site is enlarged in a way because in landscape, u have that extra width, now if i turn my phone to make it portrait, it is not re-scaling my website content, so the picture is too big in the portrait, and it forces you to scroll to the right to see the entire picture.

i am trying to avoid where you need to scroll to see the content

is it because when rotating webview, say from landscape to portrait, android just take whatever is in landscape mode and put it in portrait, without trying to resize it?

Comment: Have you tried using media queries? They work on an android galaxy.

Comment: I have the same question. Have you got solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar bug on iOS where rotating the device causing weird page zooming issues (see  https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/2 for details). I've found that a good fix for this on iOS is to change the meta viewport tag. The meta viewport tag that seems most common (and used to come with HTML5 Boilerplate) is this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

However, by removing the `initial-scale=1.0`, this bug can be sidestepped (on iOS):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Not sure if this fix works on Android, though.